# Xamarin .Net Core HttpClientHandler Method Not Implemented(VS for Mac)

Tags: xamarin, .net-core

I am writing a .net core(Standard 1.6) library that connects to my WebAPI. The WebApi requires a client certificate.

The .net core library is something being called from a Xamarin iOS app.

I cannot for the life of me send an HTTP request with a Client Certificate header.

I can use the library and post to the API with a client certificate from Visual Studio 2017 on a windows machine.

When I move the same project into my Xamarin iOS app using VS for Mac I get:
"Method Not Implemented" when setting the SslProtocol or adding the client certificate:

```
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();
            handler.ClientCertificateOptions =     ClientCertificateOption.Manual;
            handler.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;
            handler.ClientCertificates.Add(new X509Certificate2(certificate));
```

Relevant libraries:

```
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: After deep digging, although the client certificates is available to be set in the mutator, it is not implemented on ios.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, this took me quite a while but i was able to send a client certificate in a web request to use for client auth on our server.

First, as awesome as Xamarin and .netCore are, they are missing alot of the methods .net developers are used to. I was not able to build a crossplatform request that would work on both Android and ios such as the HttpWebRequest.

For ios, i created a custom class that inherits from:NSUrlConnectionDataDelegate

I then override the:

```cs
   public override void WillSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge(NSUrlConnection 
 connection, NSUrlAuthenticationChallenge challenge)
    {                 
        byte[] cert = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("clientCertificate.pfx");

        NSUrlCredential credential = iSecurity.ImportPK12File(cert, "certPassword");

        challenge.Sender.UseCredential(credential, challenge);          
    }
```

I then created a class that returns the credential:

```cs
//cert is a byte array of a .pfx file included in the resource file

//iSecurity Custom class

    NSUrlCredential credential = iSecurity.ImportPK12File(cert, "certpassword");

        public static NSUrlCredential ImportPK12File(byte[] fileBytes, string passPhrase)
        {

        var cert = new X509Certificate2(fileBytes, passPhrase);

        var options = NSDictionary.FromObjectAndKey(NSObject.FromObject(passPhrase), SecImportExport.Passphrase);

        NSDictionary[] importStatus;
        SecStatusCode statusCode = SecImportExport.ImportPkcs12(fileBytes, options, out importStatus);

        if(statusCode != SecStatusCode.Success){
            throw new Exception("Error importing certificate. ");
        }

        NSObject obj = importStatus[0]["trust"];
        IntPtr secTrustRef = obj.Handle;

        var identityHandle = importStatus[0][SecImportExport.Identity];
        var identity = new SecIdentity(identityHandle.Handle);
        var certificate = new SecCertificate(cert.GetRawCertData());

        SecCertificate[] certificates = { certificate };

        return NSUrlCredential.FromIdentityCertificatesPersistance(identity, certificates, NSUrlCredentialPersistence.ForSession);

    }
```

You may also be able to override this method and send the creds:
public override void ReceivedAuthenticationChallenge(NSUrlConnection connection, NSUrlAuthenticationChallenge challenge)
        {
            base.ReceivedAuthenticationChallenge(connection, challenge);
        }

And i may move it to there but in order to fire this off you create the delegate of your class that inherits from :NSUrlConnectionDataDelegate
and add this to your connection. Any request fired through this connection will override the method and pass the certificate.